# Same check for all policy functions

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Almost for all models, the policy functions look like this example:

```
public function index(User $user)
{
    return $user->hasPermission('view-post');
}
```

The `hasPermission` exists in the `User` model:

```
public function hasPermission($permission){
    $roleId = Auth()->user()->role_id;

    $id = $this->select('p.id')->join('role_permissions AS rp', 'rp.role_id', 'users.role_id')->join('permissions AS p', 'p.id', 'rp.permission_id')->where('rp.role_id', roleId)->where('permission', $permission)->get()->toArray();    

    return $id ? true : false; 
}
```

Then in `postController`:

```
public function index(User $user){
    if ($user->cannot('index', Post::class)) {
        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

Is there a way to avoid repeating the policy example at the top for every model and every policy function?

**I want to be able to use the method in both controller and view to check against permissions**

Comment: why would `hasPermission` be pulling the Authenticated user when the method is being called on a `User` isntance already?  you are then calling `select` on the User instance not the Auth user instance ... The Authorization system passes the currently authenticated User to your policy method for you ... you can also just call `exists()` instead of `(bool) ...->get()->toArray()`

Comment: @lagbox You mean passing the `User` as a second parameter to `hasPermission` like that `$user->hasPermission('adults-view', $user)`?

Comment: no, `$user` is already the user, it is the User instance, it knows what itself is

Comment: @lagbox I don't really understand. Can you please show with example?

Comment: `$user` is the user, the `$user` you are calling `hasPermission` is a User, the user you want to check permissions on ... you don't need to pass a User to the method or find a different User inside the method since you already know the user since you are calling the method on the user ... in the method `$this` is the User object

Comment: @lagbox I know that. But `$this` returns an object with null values

Comment: if you call that method on a non existing model then yes, but the Authorization system passes an existing model instance to your policy, the currently authenticated user

Comment: `var_dump($user);` in policy returns object of `User` with `NULL` values as well

Comment: does your route have a parameter named `user`? you are type-hinting `User $user` on your controller method and if there isn't a `user` parameter then you have a non existing User instance because of Dependency Injection instead of Route Model Binding

Comment: @lagbox No there is no user id. The URL is just `/posts`

Comment: so why do you have `User $user` in your controller method? ... you will need to get the authenticated user from the Auth system to call `cannot` on it or use `$this->authorize(...)` on the Controller to call the authorization system or the `Gate` class/facade

Comment: To be able to run functions for user model and policy. I will pass the auth user instead. Thanks for helping with that point